# Delphi nil Object in other Method

Tags: delphi, object, null

I try to free and nil the Http object in the procedure "FreeAndNilHttp" but after the call to FreeAndNilHttp the object is not free'd and nil'd.
Is it impossible to nil a variable passed to another method/procedure?

Example Code:

```
procedure FreeAndNilHttp(Http: TidHTTP);
begin
  Http.IOHandler.Free;
  Http.IOHandler := nil;
  Http.Free;
  Http := nil;
  // Http is in this procedure nil
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Http: TidHTTP;
begin
  Http := TidHTTP.Create;
  // ... create IOHandler and more stuff...

  FreeAndNilHttp(Http); // <- not working
  // Http is not nil
end;
```

Comment: You are passing a pointer to an object by value. The object is freed, but original pointer is not nil.

Comment: What is wrong with removing that procedure and writing Http.Free? Why the obsession with setting to nil that which is about to disappear anyway. Why do you feel compelled to destroy IOHandler? Won't destroying Http do that? Or do you just enjoy splatting things over and over?

Comment: Your code is a waste of CPU cycles. The local variable `Http` goes out of scope at the end of the button click handler, so the code freeing the IOHandler and setting it to nil, as well as setting the variable to nil (and thus the entire call to `FreeAndNilHttp`) are meaningless. The call to `Http.Free` at the end of the button click handler accomplishes the same thing without all the wasted code and overhead. You'd accomplish more with `Http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil); try .... finally Http.Free; end;`.

Comment: Also you will want to use try/finally to avoid leaking

Comment: This posted code was only a quick example, the "real" code is much more complex and uses try ... finally, exception handling ...

Comment: @David - this is only example code but the comment does state that an IOHandler is created and therefore is presumably not managed by the HTTP object, in which case it *does* require explicit free'ing. The NIL'ing is indeed unnecessary since, managed or not, HTTP hooks into the notification mechanism to NIL the reference if the referenced IOHandler is destroyed.  Also (at Ken) the NIL'ing is wasteful (though hardly costly) but the Free'ing part is not obviated by the fact that it is a local variable in play.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Many people on here are delphi beginners.. I would appreciate constructive, non-condescending comments. Let's welcome new delphi programmers..

Comment: @Deltics: I never said `Free` was not necessary. Read my comment again.

Comment: @Ken - Um, maybe not entirely, but you were quite clear in suggesting that one of the Free's was not necessary.  Quote: "local variable http goes out of scope ... so the code **freeing the IOHandler** and setting it to nil, as well as ...".   Both you and David overlooked the fact that the IOHandler was explicitly created (commented though not shown) and so needed to be Free'd.  `http` being a local variable or not had no bearing on *that* Free.

Comment: @Deltics: Yep, you're right. Should have been phrased differently. Should have made it more clear I meant that the IOHandler should have been free'd in the button click event as well. Apparently you can read my comments again better than I can. :-)

Comment: @Ken - No worries.  The 10 minute edit window on comments can be a  harsh mistress (to paraphrase Robert Heinlein)  :)

Comment: @Deltics: How do you get 10? I only get 5. :-)

Comment: @deltics I'm not familiar with this class. If TidHTTP isn't the owner of the handler then the owner needs to explicitly destroy it. That's going to want another separate try/finally. This procedure should still be removed though.

Comment: @David Heffernan Without the procedure this example makes no sense. and when you need to free the Http and the IOHander multiple times (because Http does not free the IOHandler object) in your code it makes sense to put it in a procedure instead of writing the same code over and over again.

Comment: Generally I like to pair calls to constructors with matching calls to destructors. It's much easier to verify correct lifetime handling. Your non-standard approach defeats that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `TidHTTP` instance behind the `Http` variable ís freed after that call, but the `Http` variable itself is indeed not nil. This is because you pass the variable by *value*. This means that the `Http` parameter in the routine points to the same object, but not to the same variable. To be able to nil the `Http` variable declared in `TForm3.Button1Click`, you need to alter the signature of the `FreeAndNilHttp` routine into:

```
procedure FreeAndNilHttp(var Http: TidHTTP);
```

Now you can pass the `Http` variable by *reference*.

But this is not necessary, because that `Http` variable in `TForm3.Button1Click` will be gone when that routine ends.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I confused myself in this case with the objects are always passed by reference thinking.

Comment: Yes, objects are passed by reference. But the refence to an object (the variable itself) follows the language rules as any other variable.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference. A parameter is passed by reference if it is a `var` parameter. A variable of class type holds a reference to an object. But when you pass one to a function you are passing a reference by value.